# [webdriver][JAVA] Mouse hover over the url adress bar

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How do i hover my mouse towards the address bar of the browser? Is it even possible? My case is that,after accessing a particular URL, when i again hover the mouse towards the address bar, i will be getting a messenger window opened.